# How to use rangeslider.js plugin in aurelia-cli project?

Tags: aurelia, rangeslider

I am going to use rangeslider.js Jquery plugin for aurelia-cli project but rangeslider does not works.

So this could be how to use jquery plugin in aurelia-cli project.

Comment: Perhaps on of the following links is helpful: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/using-jquery-ui-widgets-in-aurelia/
http://shrutidh.blogspot.de/
https://github.com/aurelia/documentation/issues/193
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-tags-input-jquery-plugin-aurelia-rajesh-vijay/

Comment: Thanks, I used ionrangeslider instead of rangeslider.js and it works as charm with aurelia with @type/ion.rangeslider library. Thanks for your kind advice.